# Mongo Aggregation giving nonsensical results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm running following mongo query:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
    {'$group': {
        '_id': 1,        
        'total_neg_sent_count': {'$sum': {'$cond': [{'$lt': ['$s', 0]}, 1, 0]}}
    }}
])
```

on following documents:

```js
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a5c8f13f35b7fc1280c60a"),
    "rT" : 5
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a5c8f13f35b7fc1280c60b"),
    "abc" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a5c8f13f35b7fc1280c60c"),
    "rT" : 0
}
```

The answer is unexpectedly:

```js
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "total_neg_sent_count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I don't know what mongo is doing here. It should return '0' as count as 's' is missing from all the documents.

Comment: Was there something in the answer here which you still do not understand?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't doing what you think it is as the missing field actually evaluates to `null` and `0` is considered to be "less than" this value:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([{ "$project": { "s": { "$ifNull": [ "$s", null ] }} }])
```

Shows the evaluation as `null` and then considering this, the raw part of your logic:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([{ "$project": { "s": { "$lt": [ "$s", 0 ] }} }])
```

Would show that this condition evaluates to `true` and therefore returns the first value from your [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) statement. So in order to consider the values of missing fields you would use [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) as was shown earlier:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": 1,        
        "total_neg_sent_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ {"$lt": [ {"$ifNull": [ "$s", 0 ] }, 0] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

When the field is missing from the document then the value returned from [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) will be 0 which of course is not [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) 0 and your expected value is returned.